# Run a Selenium test without installing ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, driver

In order to run the test I'm doing :

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

How can I replace this line so I can manage to run the code on any computer without installing chromedriver ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have a partial solution for your problem. If your project uses maven you could make use of [this project](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) and the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
<artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
<version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This solution still uses chromedriver, but you don't have to download it manually, you also don't have to set path manually.
Basically the manager takes care of everything. To initialize chrome driver you use such command:

```
ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
```

I hope it somewhat helps.